# How to click on multiple elements having same class name in protractor angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

First element html code:

```
<div class="block ng-scope" ng-repeat="skills in data.primary_skills">
                    <div class="block skillsLineItem" ng-class="{manditorySkillsLineItem:skills.mandatory, skillsLineItem:!skills.mandatory}"> 

 <label title="Testing" class="skill-name col-xs-5 text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" ng-click="toggleMandatory(skills)">
                              <!-- ngIf: skills.mandatory -->
                              <!-- ngIf: skills.userdefined -->
                              &nbsp;Testing
                            </label>
```

Second element Html code

```
<label title="Test Scripts" class="skill-name col-xs-5 text-overflow-ellipsis ng-binding" ng-click="toggleMandatory(skills)">
                          <!-- ngIf: skills.mandatory -->
                          <!-- ngIf: skills.userdefined -->
                          &nbsp;Test Scripts
                        </label>
```

In our application multiple elements having same class name and ng-click values so how can i click on multiple elements using same class or ng-click values. I have to click on both elements so please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all of them and use [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
element.all(by.css("label[ng-click*=toggleMandatory]")).each(function (label) {
    label.click();
});
```

---

You can use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter out only necessary elements:

```
element.all(by.css("label[ng-click*=toggleMandatory]")).filter(function (label, index) {
    return index <= 5;
}).each(function (label) {
    label.click();
});
```

Comment: I can't use title because skill name will be generate based on the job description.

Comment: @raghavendrat okay, how about now?

Comment: Using class or ng-click i have to do so please help me "alecxe".

Comment: Yeah its working  nicely but it is selecting all the elements, i want to click on only 6 elements ..please help me